# SIGALRM: continue execution after fired

Tags: c, unix, signals

I'm writing a code that execute cyclically some instruction (inside a for), but if current execution for some reason take a long time to be completed, i want break execution, and skip to next one. This is my code:

```
int i =0; //global var
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        signal(SIGALRM, timeout_function);
        alarm(TIMEOUT);
        if (i == 2) {
            int number;
            scanf("%d", &number);
            //simulate long operation

        } else {
            printf("current cycle: %d\n ", i);
            alarm(0);
        }
    }
```

timeout_function just print a message.
Now this is what is printed on execution:

```
current cycle: 0
current cycle: 1
cycle 2 interrupted
cycle 2 interrupted
cycle 2 interrupted
...
```

so execution of for is blocked. How can i continue normal execution of for after sigalarm?

EDIT

TIMEOUT is a value passed as argument when launch code. 
Timeout function is a simple printf:

```
void timeout_function() {
    printf("cycle %d interrupted\n", i);

}
```

Comment: what is the TIMEOUT value

Comment: Where do you print `"cycle x interrupted"`? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Answer (score 0):

Until the value of i is lesser than 2, all the alarm set are cancelled using **alarm(0)** 
The possible reason is that once the value of **i >= 2**, the program execution is waiting for the user's input to **number** 
By then the signal handler "timeout_function" is invoked.
Which means the execution is not blocked but the system is waiting for the users input.

Also after the same program with **TIMEOUT set to 1** I obtained the following result as expected.

> current cycle: 0 
>   current cycle: 1
>   time out i = 2
>   2   //user input from stdin
>   current cycle: 3
>   current cycle: 4

Comment: Ok, but scanf is put only for simulate an operation that require a lot of time, so i would skip it, then procede with next cycle (whith i=3)

Comment: @giozh can you elaborate on the above comment, I understood that whe n scanf is executed it requires lot of time yes it would wait untill the input is entered